# How to locally connect Android devices with Wifi peer 2 peer?

Tags: android, wifi, local, peer

Looking to make a local multiplayer game that can connect with other people without using Bluetooth, but rather using WiFi or local hotspots. There are multiple games in the store (one of which, [SpaceTeam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sleepingbeastgames.spaceteam&hl=en) and by connecting to the same hotspot, you can play with eachother.

The only thing Android's APIs officially support is [WiFiDirect (P2P)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html), and I tried that for a while but one of my two test devices constantly had a 'BUSY_ERROR' which I have no idea to solve. (It's a Galaxy S2 with SuperNexus rom on it, for that matter.)

In short, my question(s):

1. What would be the best way to support multiple devices (Preferably Android 2.3 and up) for local wifi connections?
2. What entails a [BUSY error](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html#BUSY)? How can I solve it? The code I used is exactly the same as the docs in the link.